# Issue Moving Files in AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I'm having trouble with the following line of AppleScript:

`move file currentFile to POSIX file "/Users/UserName/Desktop/FolderName"`

I've found that it works in one script but not in another, and I can't figure out why. In both scripts, `currentFile` is defined as an item in a list.

I've been trying different workarounds for hours but I can't get anything to work. Is there any reason why this code would work in one circumstance but not in another?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you edit your question to include an example list of files (two should suffice) that generates errors? Maybe along with the commands that would help someone reproduce the problem your facing?

Answer (score 0):

AppleScript doesn't know how to move a file.

It has to ask the `Finder` or `System Events`. In case of the `Finder` the syntax is pretty easy because the `desktop` folder of the current user is the *root* folder of the `Finder`

```
tell application "Finder"
    move file currentFile to folder "FolderName"
end tell
```

`currentFile` must be an HFS path (colon separated).

---

In case of `System Events` the syntax is slightly different and `System Events` supports also POSIX paths

```
tell application "System Events"
    move file currentFile to folder "FolderName" of desktop folder
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. ```CurrentFile``` is an HFS path, and the entire script is executed within the Finder. I tried replacing ```POSIX file "/Users/UserName/Desktop/FolderName"``` with ```folder "FolderName"```, but for some reason it still doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, I get the following error message:

error "Finder got an error: AppleEvent handler failed." number -10000 from file (alias "Macintosh HD:Users:UserName:Desktop:SourceFolder:TestFile")

Comment: `currentFile` seems to be an `alias` specifier, if so remove the `file` keyword

Comment: I tried that, and got the following error: error "Finder got an error: Handler can’t handle objects of this class." number -10010

Comment: Print the class  `display dialog (class of currentFile) as text`

Comment: The dialog says "alias".

Comment: As I thought, then `move currentFile to folder "FolderName"` in a `Finder` tell block must work.

Comment: Yep, I have no idea why it isn't working. As I mentioned in the original post, the code I had works in another similar script. The only difference between the scripts is that in the working script, the list of files is formed by a "choose file" prompt, while in this script the list of files is formed by copying a series of files to the end of an existing empty list.